# Pyspark - combine 2 rows 2 one, every 2 rows

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe here like the picture below. I would like to group every 2 rows, but in a way that:

- the first row would be that user from row 1 and 2 and
- the second row would be from row 2 and 3 etc.

Something like this:

```
---CustomerID--previous_stockcodes----stock_codes-----
```

Prices and quantities are not used, previous basket and current basket are put into one. For example, the first row of `CustomerID 12347` would be:

```
12347----[85116, 22375, 71...]-----[84625A, 84625C, ...]
```

I have written loops to do that but that's really inefficient and slow. I wonder if I can do something like that efficiently using pyspark but I am having trouble figuring that out. Thanks a lot in advance

[image]

Comment: Do you want to groupBy based on CustomerId or just 2 rows group irrespective of customerId?

Comment: I need to turn them into training set. So yes it's by CustomerID, eg row 1 and 2 of customer A, row 2 and 3 of customer A etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the next row by using `lead` function provided by spark-sql.

`lead` is a window function.

Syntax : **lead(`column_name`,`int_value`,`default_value`) over (partition by column_name order by column_name)**

`int_value` takes number of rows you want to lead from current row.

`default_value` takes input  for case when leading rows are not found

```
>>> input_df.show()
+----------+---------+----------------+
|customerID|invoiceNo|  stockCode_list|
+----------+---------+----------------+
|     12347|   537626|  [85116, 22375]|
|     12347|   542237|[84625A, 84625C]|
|     12347|   549222|  [22376, 22374]|
|     12347|   556201|  [23084, 23162]|
|     12348|   539318|  [84992, 22951]|
|     12348|   541998|  [21980, 21985]|
|     12348|   548955|  [23077, 23078]|
+----------+---------+----------------+

>>> from pyspark.sql.window import Window
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import lead,col

>>> win_func = Window.partitionBy("customerID").orderBy("invoiceNo")
>>> new_col = lead("stockCode_list",1,None).over(win_func)
>>> req_df = input_df.select(col("customerID"),col("invoiceNo"),col("stockCode_list"),new_col.alias("req_col"))
>>> req_df.orderBy("customerID","invoiceNo").show()
+----------+---------+----------------+----------------+
|customerID|invoiceNo|  stockCode_list|         req_col|
+----------+---------+----------------+----------------+
|     12347|   537626|  [85116, 22375]|[84625A, 84625C]|
|     12347|   542237|[84625A, 84625C]|  [22376, 22374]|
|     12347|   549222|  [22376, 22374]|  [23084, 23162]|
|     12347|   556201|  [23084, 23162]|            null|
|     12348|   539318|  [84992, 22951]|  [21980, 21985]|
|     12348|   541998|  [21980, 21985]|  [23077, 23078]|
|     12348|   548955|  [23077, 23078]|            null|
+----------+---------+----------------+----------------+
```